# Predefine unix socket path for ssh-agent

Tags: linux, ssh, c, session, ssh-agent

I have an application which creates an  x-session, the problem I'm having is with ssh-agent.

Lets say I have created a unix socket, and then create x-session(in this session ssh-agent is launched). So my question is:

Is it possible to launch x-session and have my socket path set as `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` for ssh-agent?

I have tried setting my socket path in `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in x-session creation command, manually checked and new `init` process contains my sockets path. But for some reason when I launch terminal(inside this session) and `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` some other path is displayed. Seems like some other process is overwriting it.

Is there any way to predefine `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` before launching x-session?

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of the (`xinit`) script which is starting the `ssh-agent`, then you can override the default socket path using the `-a PATH` option, per the man page:

```
     -a bind_address
         Bind the agent to the UNIX-domain socket bind_address.  The default is
         $TMPDIR/ssh-XXXXXXXXXX/agent.<ppid>.
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have control of xinit script.